# Passport Google Strategy Redirect 500 status code

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js

I've been working on a google authentication using passport and postgres and the redirect URI returns an error(status code 500). I think the function done is the problem, but I don't exactly know what is wrong. I tried placing logs. The serializeUser function doesn't fire, I tried logging.

Here is my passport setup

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const GithubStrategy = require('passport-github2');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local');
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('./db/db');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('here?);
    done(new Error('Serialize problem'), user.id); //first arg is the error
})
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    db.query(
        'SELECT id FROM "Users" WHERE id=$1', [id],
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error('Problemo numero 1')
            }
            console.log(results.rows[0])
            done(new Error('Problemo'), results.rows[0]); //first arg is the error




        })
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    //options for the strategy
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:9000/auth/google/redirect',
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

}, (accesToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    //passport callback function
    console.log('passport callback function fired')
    console.log(profile)
    db.query(
        `SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE id=${profile.id}`,
        (error, results) => {

            if (results.rows.length === 0) {
                const date = new Date();
                const password = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
                
                db.query(
                    'INSERT INTO "Users" (id, username, password, creation_date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)', [profile.id, profile.displayName, 0, date],
                    (error, results) => {
                        if (error) {
                            throw new Error('Insert error')
                        }
                    }


                )
                done(new Error('select error'), profile.id)
            } else {
                console.log(`Current user is id=${profile.id}`)
                done(new Error('select error 2'), profile.id)
                console.log('works?')
            }

        }
    )
}));
```

And express setup

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
let mailRouter = require('./mail');
let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('./config/db/db');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

const passportSetup = require('./config/passport');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth-routes');


var app = express();

let users = [];

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//create cookie and encrypt it
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [process.env.COOKIE_KEY]
}))

//initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});


// error handler

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send('error');
});




var port = process.env.PORT || '9000';
app.listen(port);
```

And here is my db.js file

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const { Client } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
    user,
    host,
    database,
    password,
    port
})


/*
const client = new Client()
client.connect()
*/

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params, callback) => {
        const start = Date.now()
        return pool.query(text, params, (err, res) => {
            const duration = Date.now() - start
            console.log('executed query', { text, duration, /*rows: res.rowCount*/ })
            callback(err, res)
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: I managed to get the error 'select error 2'. I'll try to see how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are passing a newly constructed error to the `done` function within the verify callback. You only need to pass an error in the first argument if something went wrong. Otherwise it should be passed `null`.

Here is a brief example of how `done` could be used:

```js
db.query(
    'INSERT INTO "Users" (id, username, password, creation_date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)', [profile.id, profile.displayName, 0, date],
    (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            // pass error through done function
            done(error)
        }
        // Pass profile object to be serialized
        done(null, profile)
    }
)
```

Reference for the `done` function: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#verify-callback

Comment: I constructed those errors to check where does the error which breaks the serialization occur. It throws "select error 2", in the else scope( where we check if the user data is saved in the db). Before that i used the documentation method, done(null, data)

Comment: Right it throws `select error 2` because its being constructed and passed to `done`. It gets to the else block because `results.rows.length > 0`. So you're saying that even when you do not pass any errors to `done` you get a 500 error?

Comment: Yes. I get to the consent page, then the redirect breaks and throws a 500 status code

Comment: Using something like this what object comes through to serializeUser? `passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('User::', user);
    done(null, user.id);
});`

Comment: "User:: user_id" , then "Failed to serialize user into session", then 
"GET /auth/google/redirect?"

Comment: Well at least serializeUser is now firing. So user is a `string`/`number` and not an `object`? If that's the case we would want to pass `user` to done: `done(null, user)` without using the access operator (.id).